# How to display the last element using join python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

python's `join` method ignores the last element in the list, but I want to be able to display without problems, look at my code:

```
import re
estoque = [0,1,20,0]                      
estoque_formated = '\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in estoque])
tamanho = [20, 34, 34.5, 40]                    
joined = f' Em estoque: {estoque_formated[0]}\n'.join(["Tamanho: " + str(elem) for elem in tamanho])                                            
print(joined)
```

The output of the script I want is this:

```
 Tamanho: 20 Em estoque 0
 Tamanho: 34 Em estoque 1
 Tamanho: 34.5 Em estoque 20
 Tamanho: 40 Em estoque 0
```

**Obs**, notice that the sizes are displayed, but it always takes the index 0 of the variable `estoque_formated` how can I get the first index and add it?  Example starting from 0 and going to 1 then 2...etc?  Well, I need to solve the problem with the index as I said, and to get it I was able to display the size and value of the `estoque_formated` variable even though it's the last element, I want to modify the script as little as possible.

Comment: It works for me. I can see all of: `20, 34, 34,5 and 40` joined by another string.

Comment: btw: `estoque_formated[0]` is always the first character of your string `estoque_formated`

Comment: @quamrana Note that the last size of the list, which in this case is 40, it does not display the 0 of the stock

Comment: What does that mean? I see all your (sizes? can you translate from portuguese for me) joined by another string inbetween. Do you understand the function of the `.join()` method? Perhaps you should update your question with exactly what you want to see printed.

Comment: @quamrana I already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you only need to `join` the resulting strings right at the end. You need `zip()` to pair up items from two different lists:

```py
estoque = [0,1,20,0]                      
tamanho = [20, 34, 34.5, 40]                    

joined = [f'Tamanho: {t} Em estoque: {s}' for t,s in zip(tamanho,estoque)]
print('\n'.join(joined))
```

Output as requested (moved the `'\n'`)

Comment: Very good, this works, how can I remove the line break from the last line?  Not that it affects anything, it's just that I have OCD

Comment: Ok, that's where you'll need `join`. I'll update . . .

Answer (score 0):

Why use `join` when you could just iterate over the two lists and print as you need.

```
estoque = [0,1,20,0]                      
tamanho = [20, 34, 34.5, 40]                    

for i in range(4):
    print(f'Tamanho: {tamanho[i]}\tEm estoque: {estoque[i]}')
```

```
Output:

Tamanho: 20 Em estoque: 0
Tamanho: 34 Em estoque: 1
Tamanho: 34.5   Em estoque: 20
Tamanho: 40 Em estoque: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just write

```py
estoque = [0, 1, 20, 0]
tamanho = [20, 34, 34.5, 40]
print(*(f"Tamanho: {t} Em estoque: {e}" for t, e in zip(tamanho, estoque)), sep="\n")
```

To get a properly padded output you could format the values accordingly:

```py
print(*(f"Tamanho: {t:4} Em estoque: {e:2}" for t, e in zip(tamanho, estoque)), sep="\n")
```

which would result in

```
Tamanho:   20 Em estoque:  0
Tamanho:   34 Em estoque:  1
Tamanho: 34.5 Em estoque: 20
Tamanho:   40 Em estoque:  0
```